# what does this error mean Request unsuccessful: nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to use colorbox and to avoid conflict i am using noConflict() method, When i load the page i dont get the error but when i open the colorbox window i see below error

```
Request unsuccessful: [Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://www.abc.com/assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.js :: .send :: line 8434" data: no]
```

Below is the code that i am using to initialize colorbox

```
  jQuery().ready(function(){
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(".cart_items").colorbox({width:"60%",Height:"50%",onLoad: function(){$j('#cboxClose').remove();},onComplete:function(){$j("form[name='cart']").bind("submit");}});
  });
```

Comment: Please clear the cache

Comment: @Baadshah : Tried clearing the cache and even opened same page in safari, there also i get the same error "Request unsuccessful: Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"

Comment: @Baadshah : Thanks, it seems to be lot of information is there in link you provided, Safari's error message was much precise to know whats the exact problem. I got the problem, It was missing link in <a> tag which has class "cart_item"

Comment: Glad i could help you :) Yes,I guessed that error before.I am not sure about that,so i didn't post it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f the url you provide is located externally to your `server`, you have permission problems. You cannot access data from another server with a `XMLHttpRequest`.

Refer :[NETWORK_ERROR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235929/network-error-xmlhttprequest-exception-101)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but thought worth to mention, I got this error when destination page was on same domain but on HTTPS.

PROBLEM SCENARIO:
Calling page: **http**://sub.domain.com/caller.aspx
Destination page: **https**://api.domain.com/uploder.aspx

SOLUTION:
Problem solved when I brought both on HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the `<form target="_blank">` on the same origin. The problem was my browser (Firefox) blocked the popup. After giving my website the permissions to open popups (Allow popups) from the browser menu, I don't get that error anymore.