# Javascript Network error while using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to open the page in my  tag. I have used following code.

Javascript:

```
function tempFunction() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = xhr.response;
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "http://stackoverflow.com/", false);

    xhr.send();
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Load" onclick="tempFunction()" />
<div id="page"></div>
```

Reference link: http://jsfiddle.net/DZmBG/3/

But when I tried by changing the URL to stackoverflow my code throw error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 49, column 13 in http://localhost:10642/WebForm2.aspx

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: NetworkError
```

Is there any thing wrong am I doing?
Can any one help me to solve this?

Thank you in advance...!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235929/network-error-xmlhttprequest-exception-101

Comment: @Pilot The reference link contains code. In that It have URL to "http://www.codecademy.com/" it works. Why other urls not working?

Answer (score 1):

(would comment but I don't have enough rep)

I get exatly the same error message (0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: NetworkError) while trying to access a local file without permission.

So I would suspect you are trying a cross-domain call which is allowed in codeacademy.com but not on stackoverflow.com, and thus it is failing.

If that's not the case someone please correct me

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.The stack overflow may not allowing a direct http hit to their server.for more help regarding this issue please see the following post (it solves one of the similar issue),Hope it will help

[Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin?answertab=votes#10143166)